# Does calling an attribute of a class instantiate an object of that class in Python?

Tags: python

If I have class Foo...

```
class Foo(object): 

    bar = True
```

- does calling `Foo.bar` instantiate an object of type Foo that gets immediately garbage collected?
- would I have to include `()` in between Foo and bar to create an instance of that type?
- if I do need the parentheses, what method do they call? `__init__()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> does calling Foo.bar instantiate an object of type Foo that gets immediately garbage collected?

No.  You've defined `Foo.bar` here as a class attribute, not an instance attribute.

> would I have to include () in between Foo and bar to create an instance of that type?

Yes, calling `Foo()` is the correct syntax to create a `Foo` object.

> if I do need the parentheses, what method do they call? `__init__()`?

First `__new__` will be called (perhaps from the superclass `object`) which actually creates the new object, and then `__init__` will be called which initialises the already existing object.